# Payments REST API generating invalid redirect urls

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Yesterday we were able to create payments and get redirect urls that could be used to approve payments. However today the redirect urls that get returned all result in pages with the message "At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to and try another option."

We are also unable to GET previous payments that have not been approved/refunded. Instead we get

```
{
    "name": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "message": "The requested resource ID was not found",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "debug_id": "ade89339d6e00"
}
```

Additional debug ids include: `d07f86c738cea,5c6da3bb0b6a`.

Answer (score 2):

There are allready several posts about this. All you can do is to wait until this issues is fixed by paypal. Fixing the url by yourself wont fix the problem.